# How can I find out a client's available cipher suites

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, tls1.2

I'm running a Node server and I need to find out somehow what cipher suites a requesting client can support.

Is this possible to do with one instance?

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I found an Apache module that can provide you with this information

https://github.com/ssllabs/sslhaf

And you can add the info to your headers in your vhost like so

```
RequestHeader set SSLHAF_HANDSHAKE "%{SSLHAF_HANDSHAKE}e"
RequestHeader set SSLHAF_PROTOCOL "%{SSLHAF_PROTOCOL}e"
RequestHeader set SSLHAF_SUITES "%{SSLHAF_SUITES}e"
RequestHeader set SSLHAF_EXTENSIONS "%{SSLHAF_EXTENSIONS}e"
```

Comment: Were you using Apache to run your NodeJs server?
Even I have a similar use case. Your help is appreciated